# Sails.js REST without action

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js

I'm trying to create a REST API in Sails.js 0.9x

I have a controller like the following:

```
UsersController = {
    list: function(req, res){
            var users [{username: "max"}, {username:'alison'}];
       res.send(users);

     },
    single: function(req, res){
            var user = {username: 'max'};
            res.send(user);
         }

};
```

How would I be able to access the URLs using an HTTP Method and the Route without specifying the action name?

For example

**HTTP GET** to **mysite.com/users/** will invoke the **list** action

**HTTP GET** to **mysite.com/users/1** will invoke the **single** action

Currently it only works when I invoke (which is **NOT** what I want)

**HTTP GET** to **mysite.com/users/list** will invoke the **list** action

**HTTP GET** to **mysite.com/users/single/1** will invoke the **single** action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a better solution

**Create/Edit the config/route.js and explicitly define the routes and their associated actions** [Link from the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/routes)

```
module.exports.routes = {
// Standard RESTful routing

// If no id is given, an array of all users will be returned
'get /user/:id?': {
    controller    : 'user',
    action        : 'find'
}
'post /user': {
    controller    : 'user',
    action        : 'create'
}
'put /user/:id': {
    controller    : 'user',
    action        : 'update'
}
'delete /user/:id': {
    controller    : 'user',
    action        : 'destroy'
},

// Override the default index action (find) by declaring an "index" method in your controller
'get /user': {
    controller    : 'user',
    action        : 'index'
}

*/
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an `index` action that redirects to other actions.

```
UsersController = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        if(req.param('idOrWhateverYouHaveDefined')) {
           this.single(req, res);
        }else {
           this.list(req, res);
        }
    },
    list: function (req, res) {
        var users[{
            username: "max"
        }, {
            username: 'alison'
        }];
        res.send(users);

    },
    single: function (req, res) {
        var user = {
            username: 'max'
        };
        res.send(user);
    }

};
```

Comment: This is clever! But but it feels a bit hacky.

Comment: This is the correct method according to Sails docs and better than core router overrides.