# Trying to update a sailsjs model with angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

```
function _addTag(tag, newTag) {
    tag.tags = [];
    tag.tags.push(newTag);
    var req = {
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/tag/update',
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {
            id: tag.id,
            tags: tag.tags
        }
    };
    return $http(req);
};
```

I'm getting a **404**.

**api/models/tag.js**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        tag: {
            type: 'array',
            defaultsTo: []
        }
    }
};
```

**api/controllers/TagController.js**

```
module.exports = {

};
```

My question is: Am I using the blueprint api correctly? Am I posting to the correct auto generated address?

Comment: Do you try to PUT to 'http://http://localhost:8081/tag/update/' + tag.id ? Without semicolon of course (so markdown engine put it by myself for some reason)

Comment: Its good to test your api first using postman chrome extension to ensure there are no 404's at that address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change url in ajax request to

```
http://localhost:8081/tag/<id>
```

Standart restFull routing explained here
[Sails.js REST without action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011729/sails-js-rest-without-action)